# Counting the number of operations to reduce an integer to 0

Tags: python

I have a positive integer, if odd it gets reduced by 1 and it counts as a step, if even is divided by 2 and it counts as a step. The goal is counting the number of steps to get the integer to 0.
Seems easy but with extremely large integers it requires a lot of time and I would like to find a way to speed up the process.

```
def counting_steps(my_number):
  steps = 0
  while my_number != 0:
    if my_number % 2 == 0:
      my_number = my_number / 2
      steps += 1
    else:
      my_number -= 1
      steps += 1
  return steps
```

I suspect working with the binary representation of the integer and using bitwise operators may be more efficient.
Any help, suggestion or lesson is really appreciate, thanks.

Comment: Remember that a division by two is a shift of your number and each bit to 1 must be reduce by one (after doing all shift needed). So you should count the number of shift requiered, i.e. the position of the most significant bit and the number of minus 1 i.e. the number of bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logarithm of a number divided by the logarithm of 2 (any base) gives the highest bit set in the number.  That's the number of divide-by-two steps.  The number of bits in the number is the number of subtract-one steps.  So:

```
from math import log

def counting_steps(n):
    return int(log(n)/log(2))+bin(n).count('1')
```

This gives the same answers as the OP algorithm.

**Edit** for some large(n) there can be an off-by-one due to floating point accuracy (try n=2**1000-1), so this doesn't use `float` and sticks to Python's infinite-precision integers.  `format` won't add the `0b` that `bin()` does, and the length of the binary number minus one is the number of divide-by-two operations needed:

```
def counting_steps(n):
    t = format(n,'b')
    return t.count('1')+len(t)-1
```

Answer (score 1):

this would be my algorithm to count steps:

```
if my_number == pow(2,n):
    #minus_1 = 1
    #divide2 = n
    steps = n+1
else:
    #minus_1 = n+1
    #divide2 = n
    steps = 2n +1
```

**Note**: pow(2,n) is the nearest 2^n that is less than my_number

To find n:

```
n=0
 while my_number != 1:
    my_number = my_number % 2 
    n +=1
```